# чтение из строки шестнадцатеричных значений в с++

Tags: c++

имеется строка в памяти вида "90 14 55 af 9b ... и т.д. "
как правильно установить флаги чтения из строки 16-ных значений?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream ss  ("10 03 02 01 ff 01 00 00 d8 03 02 01 ");
int main()
{
    int x = -1;
    //ss.setf(std::ios::hex); спотыкается на "ff", не читает в дальнейшем в 16-ном режиме, такое ощущение, что флаг не устанавливается
    //ss>>std::hex; в данном случае всё отлично работает
    while (ss >> x)
    {
        std::cout<<x<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотите вывести в консоль в итоге? Строку `"10 03 02 01 ff 01 00 00 d8 03 02 01 "`? Символ каждого байта?Или вот так `\x10 \x03 \x02 \x01 \xff \x01 \x00 \x00 \xd8 \x03 \x02 \x01"` ?

Comment: @Duracell "\x10 \x03 \x02 \x01 \xff \x01 \x00 \x00 \xd8 \x03 \x02 \x01". В консоль пока для наглядности, а так сохранить результат в std::string, но не в этом проблема. Интересует как правильно `setf` использовать, а не `ss >> std::hex;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправил:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream ss  ("10 03 02 01 ff 01 00 00 d8 03 02 01 ");

int main()
{
    int x = -1;
    while (ss >> std::hex >> x)
    {
        std::cout << std::dec << x << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Когда вы ставите манипулятор `std::hex` или `std::dec`, то они выставляются для потока, пока не будут переключены.

Вариант с `setf`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream ss  ("10 03 02 01 ff 01 00 00 d8 03 02 01 ");
int main()
{
    int x = -1;

    ss.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);
    while (ss >> x)
    {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но меня интересует как использовать setf.

Comment: Добавил вариант с `setf`

Comment: Понятно в чём заключалась ошибка. Необходимо было указывать basefield. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В общем вот вам два варианта, выбирайте какой вам нужен:

1.В десятичном виде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream ss("10 03 02 01 ff 01 00 00 d8 03 02 01 ");
int main()
{
    int x = -1;
    //ss.setf(std::ios::hex); спотыкается на "ff", не читает в дальнейшем в 16-ном режиме, такое ощущение, что флаг не устанавливается
    //ss>>std::hex; в данном случае всё отлично работает
    while (ss >> std::hex >> x)
    {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат будет:

> 16 3 2 1 255 1 0 0 216 3 2 1

2. В шестнадцатиричном виде:

`#include <iostream>`

`#include <sstream>`

```
std::istringstream ss("10 03 02 01 ff 01 00 00 d8 03 02 01 ");
int main()
{
    int x = -1;
    //ss.setf(std::ios::hex); спотыкается на "ff", не читает в дальнейшем в 16-ном режиме, такое ощущение, что флаг не устанавливается
    //ss>>std::hex; в данном случае всё отлично работает
    while (ss >> std::hex >> x)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << x << " ";
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Ответ будет:

> 10 3 2 1 ff 1 0 0 d8 3 2 1

Comment: А теперь тоже самое, но без `ss >> std::hex >> x`, а с применением ss.setf(И ВОТ ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ И ВОЗМОЖНО ЛИ ЭТО ВООБЩЕ).